# Initializing entity list member which is part of one entity from result of procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

I have one entity named `AlertRuleEntity` and other named `OccuredEventEntity`. One alert can have multiple events under it. Means relationship between alert and rule is one to many.

This is how my entities looks like

```
public class AlertRuleEntity
{
    public List<OccuredEventEntity> OccuredEventEntityList { get; set; }
    public int AlertId { get; set; }
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public string RuleType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OccuredEventIds { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string AppType { get; set; }
    public string AppTypeParameter { get; set; }
    public string Penalty { get; set; }
    public string RuleDate { get; set; }
}

public class OccuredEventEntity
{
    public int OccuredEventId { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is part of my C# DAAB method

```
m_DbCommand = new MySqlCommand("GetAlertRuleDetails;", m_DbConnection);
m_DbCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("alertId", alertId));
m_DbCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
dtAlertRuleEntityList = ExecuteReader(m_DbCommand);

if (dtAlertRuleEntityList != null)
{
    if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            alertRuleEntity = new AlertRuleEntity();
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AlertId"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AlertId"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.AlertId = Convert.ToInt32(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AlertId"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleId"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleId"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.RuleId = Convert.ToInt32(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleId"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleName"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleName"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.RuleName = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleName"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleType"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleType"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.RuleType = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleType"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["Description"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["Description"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.Description = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["Description"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["OccuredEventIds"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["OccuredEventIds"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.OccuredEventIds = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["OccuredEventIds"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["OccuredEventIds"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["OccuredEventIds"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.OccuredEventEntityList = GetOccuredEventDetails(alertRuleEntity.OccuredEventIds);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["UserName"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["UserName"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.UserName = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["UserName"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppName"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppName"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.AppName = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppName"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppType"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppType"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.AppType = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppType"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppTypeParameter"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppTypeParameter"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.AppTypeParameter = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AppTypeParameter"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["Penalty"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["Penalty"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.Penalty = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["Penalty"]);
            if (dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleDate"] != null && !dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleDate"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                alertRuleEntity.RuleDate = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleDate"]);
            alertRuleEntityList.Add(alertRuleEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Till date I used two procedures to get result.

```
GetAlertRuleDetails(IN alertId INT(11))
GetOccuredEventDetails(IN occuredEventIds VARCHAR(255))
```

Now I need to do it from single procedure call only. I have created new procedure. This procedure will return entries of rules and respective events at the same time.

What is the proper way to initialize `OccuredEventEntityList` of `AlertRuleEntity` from the result of this new procedure